# Calculating Days from one month to the next in a table/query/report

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I have a query that returns the number of days per month in a date span, ie, `Start Date = 6/10/2020`, `End Date = 10/28/2025`. The query returns: (disregard the periods behind the numbers).

```
Years.    Jan.  Feb.  Mar.  Apr.  May.  Jun.  Jul.  Aug.  Sep.  Oct.  Nov.  Dec.  
2020.                                    20.   31.   31.   30.   31.   30.   31
2021.      31.   28.   31.   30.   31.   30.   31.   31.   30.   31.   30.   31
2022.      31.   28.   31.   30.   31.   30.   31.   31.   30.   31.   30.   31.  
2023.      31.   28.   31.   30.   31.   30.   31.   31.   30.   31.   30.   31.  
2024.      31.   28.   31.   30.   31.   30.   31.   31.   30.   31.   30.   31.  
2025.      31.   28.   31.   30.   31.   30.   31.   31.   30.   28.
```

I am searching for a way to calculate the Sum of June 2020 with July 2020, and the July 2020 with August 2020 and so on throughout the entire record set. So, July 2020 should = 51, August 2020 should = 82 and so on.

Any suggestions?

I have tried Next, Last, First, and who knows every different approach.

Comment: May be easier to implement in the original query if it added to the post.

Comment: If you add sample data then it will be easier for us to understand. [Minimum Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: This is the Crosstab Query used.

TRANSFORM Count(qryYearMonthDatePart.Month) AS CountOfMonth
SELECT qryYearMonthDatePart.Years, Sum(qryYearMonthDatePart.Month) AS [Total Of Month]
FROM qryYearMonthDatePart
GROUP BY qryYearMonthDatePart.Years
PIVOT Format([WhatDate],"mmm") In ("Jan","Feb","Mar","Apr","May","Jun","Jul","Aug","Sep","Oct","Nov","Dec");

Comment: The StartDate and End Date are passed through the Crosstab Query with this: SELECT tblSentence.Sentence_ID, tblSentence.Date_Sentenced, tblSentence.Date_Committed, tblSentence.Total_Prior_Time, tbl20YearGCT.Good_Conduct_Time, tbl20YearGCT.Full_Term_Days, tbl20YearGCT.FSA_Projected, tbl20YearGCT.GCT_Days FROM tbl20YearGCT RIGHT JOIN tblSentence ON tbl20YearGCT.Sentence_Months = tblSentence.Sentence_ID;

Comment: So, if it's just a normal summation then won't `(Jun + Jul)` work for you?

Comment: I wish it was that simple. The goal is to count the previous month with the current month throughout the entire returned record-set.

Comment: "does not work" does not tell us much. What happens - error message, wrong result, nothing? Did you use that posted query as source for another query (or a report) where you do the progressive calcs?

Comment: The sum must start with the first row & column (not null) June, 2020 which is 20. July should be Junes number plus July equaling 51. August would be 82, September should be 112, October 143, November 173, December =204. Year Column and Row 2021 should start with January 2021 = December 2020, 204 plus January 2021 = 235. February 2021 = 263 and so on. All the way through the end of the record set. The pass through dates (Date_Committed and GCT_Days) are from a form that supplies the criteria for the Crosstab query. The results are shown in query results and then displayed in a report.

Comment: Can't do that sort of "running sum" with data in that horizontal arrangement. Alternative is VBA calculating progressive value and saving to a "temp table". A really ugly approach would be 65 textboxes with DSum() expressions.

Comment: Correction, 72 texboxes calling DSum() or custom VBA function.

Comment: Well, just learned something new. A running sum query can be used as source for a CROSSTAB. That will produce the sample output. Edit question to show your raw data as formatted text tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A running sum query can be used as source for a CROSSTAB. Given data like:

| ID | EffDate |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 10/4/2021 |
| 2 | 11/15/2021 |
| 3 | 12/22/2022 |
| 4 | 1/8/2022 |
| 5 | 2/11/2022 |
| 6 | 3/28/2022 |
| 7 | 4/9/2022 |
| 8 | 5/2/2022 |
| 9 | 6/30/2022 |
| 10 | 7/12/2022 |
| 11 | 8/31/2022 |
| 12 | 9/2/2022 |

Query1:
Example calculates how many days are in each month and uses that for running sum. Adjust to handle your filtered dataset and method of calculating days of month.

```
SELECT ID, Year(EffDate) AS Yr, Format(EffDate,"mmm") AS Mo, (
    SELECT Sum(Day(DateSerial(Year(EffDate), Month(EffDate) +1,0))) 
    FROM Dates AS Dupe WHERE Dupe.ID<=Dates.ID) AS RunDays
FROM Dates;
```

Query2:

```
TRANSFORM Max(RunDays) AS MaxOfRunDays
SELECT Yr
FROM Query1
GROUP BY Yr
PIVOT Mo In ("Jan","Feb","Mar","Apr","May","Jun","Jul","Aug","Sep","Oct","Nov","Dec");
```

| Yr | Jan | Feb | Mar | Apr | May | Jun | Jul | Aug | Sep | Oct | Nov | Dec |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | 31 | 61 | 92 |
| 2022 | 123 | 151 | 182 | 212 | 243 | 273 | 304 | 335 | 365 |  |  |  |

**ADDENDUM**
On further review, I find it is possible to do this without correlated subquery for running sum.

Query1:

```
SELECT ID, EffDate, Year(EffDate) AS Yr, Format(EffDate,"mmm") AS Mo, 
DateSerial(Year(EffDate), Month(EffDate),1) AS BOM, 
DateSerial(Year(EffDate),Month(EffDate)+1,0) AS EOM, 
(SELECT Min(EffDate) FROM Dates WHERE EffDate Between #11/11/2021# And #7/15/2022#) AS FirstDay, 
IIf(EOM Between #11/11/2021# And #7/15/2022#,EOM,EffDate) AS LastDay, 
LastDay-IIf(BOM BETWEEN #11/11/2021# AND #7/15/2022#,BOM,EffDate)+1 AS Days, 
[LastDay]-[FirstDay]+1 AS RunDays
FROM Dates
WHERE EffDate Between #11/11/2021# And #7/15/2022#;
```

Query2:
Same CROSSTAB from above

| Yr | Jan | Feb | Mar | Apr | May | Jun | Jul | Aug | Sep | Oct | Nov | Dec |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | 16 | 47 |
| 2022 | 78 | 106 | 137 | 167 | 198 | 228 | 240 |  |  |  |  |  |

Comment: I will try this......get back to you soon.

Comment: I went with Version 2 of Query 1:
SELECT Dates.EffDate, Year(EffDate) AS Yr, Format(EffDate,"mmm") AS Mo, DateSerial(Year(EffDate),Month(EffDate),1) AS BOM, DateSerial(Year(EffDate),Month(EffDate)+1,0) AS EOM, (SELECT Min(EffDate) FROM Dates WHERE EffDate Between #1/15/2024# And #7/15/2026#) AS FirstDay, IIf(EOM Between #1/15/2024# And #7/15/2026#,EOM,EffDate) AS LastDay, LastDay-IIf(BOM Between #1/15/2024# And #7/15/2026#,BOM,EffDate)+1 AS Days, [LastDay]-[FirstDay]+1 AS RunDays
FROM Dates
WHERE (((Dates.EffDate) Between #1/15/2024# And #7/15/2026#));

Comment: However my results returned do not give the January 2024 results nor the July 26 result. January 2024 and July 2026 are blank. I am using Query 2 to grab the data in Query 1 listed above.

Comment: Works for me. What are EffDate values for January 2024 and July 2026? Are they between the date range?

Comment: My temporary table has dates danging from 1/1/2024 and 8/31/2026.

Comment: Also, the return on the query will only calculate on Months that have a date, ie, if I don’t have a date in the table that represents a month in the date span, that month/year is empty on the return record set from the query.

Comment: You were asked to provide sample of your data, although at this point not sure that would help. I can't explain failure with your data because I cannot replicate failure. You could post in a discussion forum that allows attaching files and provide your db. And yes, can only retrieve data that exists.  Forcing records for years with no data would require either dummy data in table or join (or UNION) to a dataset that has all possible month/years.

Comment: How do I post in a discussion forum? I am new to StackOverflow and trying to get this solved.

Comment: accessforums.net or access-programmers.co.uk or utteraccess.com or vbaexpress.com

Comment: Wow, I have it working. I actually have to put the actual start and end date into the table, ie 1/15/2024 and 7/15/2024 must be in the temporary table to get the running sum of days per month. I will be using a form for the Between statement, ie Forms!frmSentence1.StartDate, Forms!frmSentence1.EndDate as the date criteria. Obviously I will have to create a temporary table that will supply a Month/Day/Year for every month between the StartDate and EndDate.

Thank you for your help! Fingers crossed!

Comment: Well, that was not necessary for me. If I have 1/17/2024 then I get 15 days for Jan 2024.

Comment: I don't understand either. I didnt get the same results. Well, I have the answer and a solution to get it to do whatI need. Thank You for your help.